# Always get token_rejected error when trying to call yahoo contacts API

Tags: php, yahoo-api

In according to yahoo documentation I went through following steps:

1. recieve request token
2. redirect user to yahoo auth page
3. on callback page use token from GET parameter to get oauth_token
4. receive oauth_token and trying to call contacts api to get list of contacts with GET request by following url:

   http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$xoauth_yahoo_guid.
   '/contacts?format=json&oauth_consumer_key='._YH_APP_CK.
   '&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_nonce=noncedata&oauth_version=1.0'.
   '&oauth_signature='._YH_APP_SK.'%26'.$_SESSION['yahoo_token_secret'].
   '&oauth_token='.$oauth_token.
   '&oauth_timestamp='.date_timestamp_get(date_create());

where

```
$xoauth_yahoo_guid // user id
_YH_APP_CK // consumer key
_YH_APP_SK // consumer secret key
$_SESSION['yahoo_token_secret'] // secret token that was received from yahoo
```

I used `PLAINTEXT` as `oauth_signature_method` and concatenated secret key and secret token to set signature as said in documentation but still I get `token_rejected` error, can anybody help me find the cause? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have session_start(); at the beggining of your php script?

Comment: yes, session works correctly, `$_SESSION['yahoo_token_secret']` has a right value

Comment: Check this info http://nullinfo.wordpress.com/oauth-yahoo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT` cannot be used for `http://` requests. SO `oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1` should be used in this case.
Following code can be used for creating an oauth_signature with HMAC-SHA1 method:
https://github.com/joechung/oauth_yahoo/blob/master/getacctok.php